# PyQt5. Painting On top of a Button while Keeping the Button Active

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qt6

I am new to PyQt, but I can't find this question asked. I am trying to have a QT widget that paints on top of a QTbutton. So the user presses the button and a nice rectange is colored on top of the button, but the button still must remain active and ideally the color has a low opacity to read the lettering. I am trying to create a poker range training similar to below where the user presses the button and the square highlights. Now I am trying to add weights so that the square doesn't always fully hightlight (ie can't just change the background).
[image: PokerRange]

I have tried a stack Layout but then I lose the button functionality because the draw widget is on top. Any ideas about how to go about building this would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: A better and more appropriate solution would be to paint *the* button, overriding its `paintEvent()` in a subclass. Note that, from the look of your Ui, you probably would just use a QTableView with an appropriate model (or a QTableWidget) and a custom delegate.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Thank you! @musicamante

Answer (score 1):

After some very good guidance from @musicamante (thank you!), I was able to solve the problem. Here is a minimum viable implementation

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class DrawRangeButton(QPushButton):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        r = event.rect()
        p = QPainter(self)
        p.fillRect(0, 0, int(r.width()/2), int(r.height()), self.color)
        p.drawText(r, Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)

    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = Qt.blue
        self.text = text

    def changeColor(self):
        print("TEST")
        self.color = Qt.red

class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainWidget = QWidget() 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.mainWidget)
                
        self.button = DrawRangeButton("TEST")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button.changeColor)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Test()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Note that you should also always call `self.update()` whenever you change something that could affect painting (so, in this case, after setting `self.color` in `changeColor()`).